# How to install pandas for python 3.5 on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

i am new to python and want to learn data analysis through **python 3.5**, while installing **pandas** through cmd it is showing warnings.

Comment: You can check [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pandas/796/introduction-to-pandas#t=201607270657357583183), I use `anaconda` and it works for me very nice.

Comment: Post the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install pandas
```

in cmd works fine. However you can refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html for installation of pandas with Anaconda or Miniconda.

Answer (score 0):

Install Anaconda and all your problems will be gone you can install 720+ packages related to python.
conda install pandas
conda install numpy
conda install ......

Comment: pandas works fine on normal python there is no need to overcomplicate things with annnaconda here